# Are questions about software usage to help programming still on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

[A question about putty was asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27477658/save-putty-ouput-to-file-from-command-line) a long, long time ago and answered. But would a similar question regarding putty (or any other similar tool) be on topic? We state in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) that a question can be about

> - software tools commonly used by programmers

but shouldn't this be more reduced to IDEs instead of any software that a programmer might use?

I mean, the description is a bit broad. Many programmers also use Chrome (or any internet browser) or Excel. Shouldn't we narrow down our software descriptions a bit?

Comment: The 'and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development' part of the quote in the help center is important to get the full meaning :)

Comment: I agree with you, but just to add another question: Is logging stuff from putty unique to software development?

Comment: That question is asked in the context of running a batch file which I think is just enough about programming to be on-topic.

Comment: So the specific use case and not the specific use of the software is what matters. ok, I think if all this is gathered in an answer satisfies my question :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> but shouldn't this more reduced to IDEs instead of any software that a programmer might use?

No, it shouldn't. Is [vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vim) an IDE? What about [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git)?

> I mean, the description is a bit broad. Many programmers also use chrome (or any internet browser) or Excel. Shouldn't we narrow down our software descriptions a bit?

No, we shouldn't. The qualifier in the description Patrice mentions ("[...] and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"), plus a dab of common sense, should be enough to restrict its usage appropriately.

(I feel that it might make sense to use slightly softer wording than "unique to" in the aforementioned qualifier, but that shouldn't matter if it isn't taken *too* literally -- otherwise e.g. the vast majority of Git questions might be deemed off-topic merely because Git can also be used for version control in contexts unrelated to programming.)

> Is logging stuff from putty unique to software development?

As rene points out, this remark in the question...

> I know this is easily done using the GUI but in my case it has to be done automatically.

... is just about enough to justify it being here. Without it, I'd lean towards "off-topic/general computing", or possibly "off-topic/belongs to Super User". The [putty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/putty) tag wiki seems to concur:

> PuTTY is an open source SSH and Telnet client. Use this tag only if your question relates to *programming* PuTTY or using PuTTY-based APIs. Questions relating to using or troubleshooting PuTTY usage are off-topic.

It is also worth noting that [Super User has a fairly active PuTTY tag](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/putty).