# Are [sed], [awk] and text processing questions valid on Stack Overflow anymore?

Tags: discussion, support, downvotes

These days, I'm seeing some constant disapproval to answers for questions under the tags [awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/awk) and [sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sed), or any questions involving command-line text processing on Stack Overflow. Do these questions remain valid for this community? I constantly see well formatted questions, with a valid input and proper testable input output constantly getting down-voted (both questions and answers).

I'm also seeing comments from the same user.

I wanted to know for sure before commenting to the person that these are still valid questions for the community.

Comment: You can't reasonably pull this off yourself, not knowing exactly who voted puts you on a very slippery slope.  Never accuse a user directly.  Just flag a post that you think was downvoted incorrectly with a custom flag to have a moderator look at it, be sure to mention that you see a pattern.  They have a way to communicate concerns effectively, not being involved directly themselves.  I didn't see one in [awk] btw, might have something to do with my filters.

Comment: @HansPassant : Thanks a lot, just did flag it quoting this link. Hope the mods know the repetitive patten

Comment: Uh, you write a (sometime small) program for sed and awk, ergo it's programming.  Why would that be at all off-topic?  If so, does that mean Perl and Python too?

Comment: Looking at the discussion under the question with your most recent sed answer the disapproval appears to be because he/she feels that is a duplicate - not that it is off topic

Comment: @MartinSmith: I can share multiple such findings given the previous history with that person. Though I know that it was that person, I didn’t share my most recent question here. I just wanted I clarify this topic the next time someone questions such questions

Comment: In general, `sed` and `awk` questions are fine on SO.  They are both tools that require programs to be written — and the questions are usually about what's wrong with the program that the questioner has written.  (Or there are the poorer standard questions where the OP wants the program written for them, etc; such questions are not so welcome, of course, but that's not because of the tag.)  I also happen to have gold badges in both the [tag:awk] and [tag:sed] tags on SO.

Comment: But this meta post is only useful for you if the reason for downvotes is because people on the site believe these questions are inherently invalid. In the specific example I looked at [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6TJN.png) (where you link to this Q as vindication) the objection was that the Q is a duplicate. So the point to address is whether it is a duplicate or not - the comments about formatting and MVCE are not relevant until that is addressed.

Comment: @MartinSmith : Please do understand that I’ve not raised this for the first time the person is doing this. I’ve seen a number of posts which weren’t duplicates that had this behaviour. I’m happy to delete this question if you’d like but I can point numerous questions that suggest what I’ve addressed today

Comment: He insisted on making his name public.  I'm very happy that my tag filters work well.  The world has to be in balance, for every five awesome users like you there needs to be one user that counters the good vibes.  Hopefully you can find the other four.

Comment: Inian: Do you have any better examples of incorrect dup-closing?  If you just read the question without your answer, it's obviously a duplicate of any `bash` quoting-a-single-quote question.  And if we want that question to be about MacOS `sed`'s apparent bug with single quotes on its command line, we should edit the question to actually pass it some, instead of having a question where the normal fix leads to another problem on that platform.  @Jww Downvoting the answers as well as the question is ridiculous, and improper, though, IMO.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Thanks for your points Peter, as I've replied in my comments above to Martin Smith, this has happened a number of times before. I for one clearly dislike getting my accepted answers downvoted. I had asked the OP a few times to un-accept my answer, so that I can delete it, because of jww's actions of downvoting for the obvious reasons. I can't find one right away, but I can share this meta link in the future, when he exhibits this behavior. Let alone me, how would this downvoting reflect on a new guy, who has around just 500+ rep when his well explained answer got a -ve feedback?

Comment: Everything about what JWW did on the linked Q is ok (maybe including DV the question for lack of research), *except* for downvoting good answers.  That's totally not cool, and unjustified even if you don't like the question they were posted on.  I hate it when people do that to my answers, too.  But I've never considered deleting them because of a downvote from a random hater, if I'm still confident it's a good answer after re-reading it to check for mistakes.  IDK why you'd ask the OP to un-accept.  That makes no sense.  You want to remove useful content from SO because of incorrect votes?

Comment: @PeterCordes: Yes, may be its just me, the down-vote on a well qualified answer is something I wasn't able to accept till now. I think I can change that moving forward.

Comment: Just to re-iterate: since it's happening consistently, that's a problem to be addressed, separately from you learning to accept random unexplained downvotes.   In general people who DV my answers without pointing out a mistake in them obviously fail to appreciate my genius.  Or are assholes who think that good answers on mediocre questions deserve downvotes.  (I haven't run into people who DV even *good* questions on a whole topic they don't like; that just makes no sense.  That's what tag filters are for.)

Comment: FWIW, awk and sed questions generally get a good reception on Unix & Linux.

Comment: I think the discussion in the comments of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48604954/3266847) illustrates the disagreement between jww and users like Inian and myself well.

Comment: @Peter, Inian, Joshua, whomever - There is absolutely no reason not to *"have a talk with me"*. Feel free to contact me by email. My email address is sitting there plain as day in my profile. I am also all over the web due to mailing list participation and free software contributions.

Comment: @jww: That's up to the moderators, IMO.  It's also *not* what this question is supposedly about.  This meta question is just asking whether sed/awk are on topic *at all*.  That's why we're only talking about your voting habits in comments, instead of answers.  (I don't think it really needs debate, and hopefully you will hear from a moderator soon.  Or maybe a generic question about whether it's appropriate to downvote correct answers on questions you don't like would make sense, if there isn't one already.)

Comment: When you said *"or any questions involving text processing"* you meant *"command-line text processing"*, because SO has lots or text-processing with scripted or compiled languages. Perhaps the better thing to ask is whether command-line text-processing questions (and other generic UNIX command-line utility questions) can equally be asked on SO rather than SuperUser.

Comment: @YvetteColomb interestingly, the [editor pointed the callout to themself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/368711/3).  Still probably an irrelevant detail, but worth considering.

Comment: the OP clearly called out the user in the comments before the edit. I believe the user (they can correct me if I'm wrong) made the edit as it was obvious whom it was referring to.

Comment: A friend of mine [sed] that these questions are [awk]ward on the site just the other day.

Comment: @jww can you hold off writing so many comments suggesting that people post on other sites? The other sites are [not always wanting our questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work/10250#10250).

Comment: @Inian - If you edit the question so that it either (1) addresses my voting history or (2) addresses on-topicness of duplicate questions then I will respond. Otherwise I won't respond with the conflation of topics and the misdirections and inaccurate statements..

Comment: @jww  I don't believe your voting should come under the scrutiny of a meta post. Honestly, you're allowed to downvote content you don't think is ok and you're allowed to your opinion, The vast majority of your votes are upvotes. Perhaps make a case for why you think they're off topic in an answer?

Comment: @YvetteColomb: Just to clarify, not for once I mentioned the user in this meta post as the person down voting.

Comment: @Inian you linked to a comment made by that user in the comments under this question, not long after writing this question. The comment is now deleted. That link made it clear whom you were referring to. I have no issue with wanting to clarify whether these are on topic, as there's been a lot of comments recommending to use other sites. It's a shame it involved some accusations against another person, that really needed to  be handled with a mod flag. Two separate issues. Perhaps consider rewording your question to focusing about the disagreement without accusation.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

> These days, I'm seeing some constant disapproval to answers for
>   questions under the tags awk and sed, or any questions involving text
>   processing on Stack Overflow. Do these questions remain valid for this
>   community?

sed and awk process special-purpose scripting languages.  The types of scripts most often used with them are short enough to specify on the command line, but that's unimportant.  Writing sed and awk scripts is an exercise in programming, and questions about doing so are therefore within SO's purview.  Anyone systematically downvoting such questions or answers is, at best, performing a disservice to the community.

Additionally, inasmuch as sed and awk are often used in writing shell scripts, which is an on-topic exercise, the [sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sed) and [awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/awk) tags are useful for better characterizing questions about writing shell scripts that use these.  Such questions should also be tagged with the shell name, typically (here) [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash).  When the tags are used in this capacity, I'm not sure I even agree with the tag wiki that questions about these tools' command-line options are off topic.  Such questions are analogous to questions about how various languages' built-in functions work.

The fact that SO *has* decently-populated [sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sed) and [awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/awk) tags supports (but does not prove) the proposition that questions about those tools can be on-topic here today.

> I constantly see well formatted questions, with a valid input and
>   proper testable input output constantly getting down-voted (both
>   questions and answers) by a certain user (don't want to name it).

Obviously, you cannot be certain who downvoted a question, but if you see a pattern of a specific user commenting -- incorrectly -- that questions about sed, awk, and / or text processing in general are off-topic, then it would be reasonable to make your own comment to dispute such claims.  For this purpose, it will be useful to have this Meta discussion to refer to.  If you suspect that the negative comments are accompanied by systematic downvoting then this would be a good justification for a modflag.

Answer (score 29):

If we look at the excerpt for [sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sed), since 2016, it says:

> Use this tag only if your question relates to programming using sed or sed-based APIs. Questions relating to using or troubleshooting sed command-line options itself are off-topic.

[awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/awk) has the same notice (with sed replaced by awk, of course), added by the same user.

This also reflects the information given in the [help/on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page: a problem has to be *unique* to software development.

For awk and sed, that's a thin line. Many of these questions could be asked in the context of linux system administration, and thus aren't necessarily related to programming. That makes it possible to interpret them as off-topic.

You could make the argument that since these question are not necessarily programming related, they would fit better on SU. And SU does have a [sed](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sed) and an [awk](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/awk) tag.

However, these text processors can take complex commands that filter and transform data, which might be analogous to an SQL statement (and asking questions about SQL statements certainly is on-topic here).

Also the tags on SU have less than 1000 questions per tag, while those on SO have around 20.000 questions per tag.

For me, I'd say plain general use questions (e.g. *How do I open a file in awk*) would be off-topic. Any questions regarding creating long commands to filter, output or transform text would be on-topic. In between, there's a grey area, but considering the much higher amount of questions on SO, we should not be overly critical to such questions.

Comment: "a problem has to be unique to software development" - if that were to be followed by the letter, you would need to disallow a whole lot of questions. In my experience, that rule has always been applied very leniently.

Comment: @l4mpi If you read the last sentence of my question, you see I advocate leniency too, and think most of these questions should be considered on-topic for SO.

Comment: Yes you do, so maybe you shouldn't prominently quote a rule that neither you yourself nor the rest of SO follow.

Comment: The rule is there for a reason. I'm trying to make a balanced argument, and note that I'm very aware of the rule, before someone comes in, downvotes, and notes that I haven't read the rules. If you want to convince someone that thinks these questions are off-topic, a well-balanced argument often works better than just ignoring the rules and stating they're on-topic.

Comment: @l4mpi "if that were to be followed by the letter, you would need to disallow a whole lot of questions" -- I'd say that is precisely why we use it as a guiding principle rather than as a hard rule. (FWIW, [a few more remarks of mine on the matter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/365475/2751851).)

Comment: “_with sed replaced by awk, of course_” – do you mean `s/sed/awk/g`?

Comment: The data about which SE site has more questions with a certain tag (esp. of course between SO and SU, maybe between SO and SF) is interesting - maybe it should be part of the popup auto-complete prompts when selecting a tag.  (i.e., "6.8K questions here, 950 questions over there on SU").  Would that help coalesce the community for those tags?

Comment: @DidierL — that's using `sed` to replace itself with `awk`, isn't it?  It's fiddlier in `awk`: `gsub(/sed/, "awk", $0)` and a print operation, is it not (or replacing the `/` with `"` also works).

Comment: I find the comparison in numbers of questions between the two sites to be unconvincing. Stack Overflow is much more popular than SuperUser by orders of magnitude; there will likely be more questions on this site than the other for any given shared tag. For instance, there are more questions tagged `ms-word` here (12523) than are tagged `microsoft-word` on SU (5288). Does that mean users should ask how to open an RTF file in Word non-programmatically here? Of course not.

Answer (score 11):

I have to admit that `sed` is getting pretty rarely used these days for more than inline regex search and replace; but it is still used from time to time and it's pretty arcane.

On the other hand, `awk` is pretty darn powerful. Every time I reach for it I end up writing ten to twenty lines of `awk` code right there. Specified on the command line. Bah. If `bash`'s builtins can't handle it these days, the `awk` to do it is not all that likely to fit on a line.

I took a look at the sed and awk tags. They're attracting a lot of give-me-the-codez questions but there's some good ones there and somebody's writing a lot of good `awk` answers.

Leave the tags. Check the questions. Oh, and consider if said misbehaving user needs a talking to.

Comment: PERL's s// and m// operators are sed with powerful $variables, and advanced regex syntax like lookbehind/ahead.

Answer (score 6):

I don't see why they would not be relevant to SO. 
SO is a community of developers/coders/technical people helping each other. 
ruling out scripts/tools like awk and sed from here would be unhelpful for the community as these tools/scripts are part of daily work for some of us. 
if you removed/downvoted (effectively discourage) questions related to these from the community, a lot of other "borderline" programming topics/concepts (regex comes to mind) would also have to be taken out of the community.

In my opinion, if its something that helps us to get our jobs done, I don't see why it would be outside of SO. specially if the understanding of the topic is not something a non-developer/technical person would be familiar with.

Comment: A lot of regex questions end up with low future value (for future readers), though, because I think it's hard to find a Q&A that needs a regex similar enough to what you're doing.  It's easier to just learn regexes instead of wading through SO Q&As looking for one with a pattern or searching / replacing that you can adapt to your case with different literal text.  But as long as there are people that *enjoy* solving regex challenges, people that want someone else to write a regex for them can apparently get that on SO and everyone wins.  Everyone else can ignore the tag.

Comment: @PeterCordes I think regex answers have a great future value, but only for those that are capable of reading the regex and changing it accordingly to their needs.

Comment: @Xatenev: Sure, but the problem is for those future readers to be able to find the right regex Q&A with a search.  The applicability of a regex often hinges on features of the problem that are very hard to describe in words, and often don't get described.  It's just "data like this".  And if you do know how to describe it in terms that are useful for regexing, you would often know how to write a regex yourself and not need to search.

Comment: @PeterCordes I agree.

Comment: my point is that "not exactly code" questions that are of a nature close to our technical job requirements (this is where awk, regex and many others sit) should be an acceptable part of SO. and not discouraged.
your argument with regex, can be expanded to pretty much all other questions including coding ones. since we dont live in an ideal world, and the post is asking for a black or white anwser/opinion. my black/white opinion is that i prefer to have stuff that is not relevant in SO as well as the relevant, instead of nothing at all. 
the upvote system filters out the pointless questions.